# Problem with precision when convert from WKT to shapefile

Tags: shapefile, well-known-text, pygdal

I have a problem with converting from WKT to shapefile in pygdal. In wkt I have fields with precision (for example real 7.2). When I create a shapefile I have field numeric with no precision (numeric 7.0). I can't find problem.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you converting a raw WKT to a geometry? I am interested in finding out how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a shapefile with precision. The DBF format (which is what the shapefile uses to store attribute information) can store decimal places as part of the `numeric` data type ([see here](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage9.0/server1/dbf_field_types_and_specifications.htm)) so your problem is probably that you've not told pygdal what precision you want on your numeric.